# reference issue in javascript collection

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having some kind of reference issue in javascript collection.

Here is the plunker -> [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vv8mLQAhf0hTGuoSWJyf?p=preview)

The issue is, when I am doing

```
approverSteps[0].loadedApprovers.push({prop1: 'test'});
```

Then the loadedApprovers property of second element in the approverSteps collection i.e (approverSteps[1](https://plnkr.co/edit/Vv8mLQAhf0hTGuoSWJyf?p=preview)) is also getting updated. I know it's reference issue but any idea how to fix it.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should put your code in your question and describe the actual problem you're encountering - what happens, what you expect to happen, how they are different, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All the items get their `loadedApprovers` array as a reference to the same empty array.

```
const approvalStepDefault = {
  loadedApprovers: [] // this array
};
```

Arrays are passed by reference too (they're objects).

Try this:

```
// no need for approvalStepDefault

let data = {
    steps: [{id: '01'},{id: '02'}]
};

let approverSteps = (data.steps || []).map(item => {
    const obj =  Object.assign({}, item); // copy item so the original item will remain intact (remove this line if you don't want to work on a clone)
    obj.loadedApprovers = [];             // brand new array for each object
    return obj;
});

approverSteps[0].loadedApprovers.push({prop1: 'test'});
console.log(approverSteps);
```